# Headphones problem

Tags: sound, panel, headphones

I have a problem and I can't find a solution. I was searching for 3 hours and still nothing. My front panel audio don't work. And when i plug headphones into back panel works only right headphone. What should I do i really need it.

Comment: Are you sure that the headphones work?